# Finding Integers to Satisfy a Condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Below is the question I have to answer. I'm not sure how to attack it. Any tips?

> For how many integers
>   $n$ between $1$ and $6 \cdot 10^6$
>   does there exist at least
>   one pair of integers $(x, y)$ such that
>   $xn
> + 60y
> = 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The equation

$$xn + 60 y = 1$$ has a solution $(x, y)$ if and only if the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $60$ is $1$. Now try counting how many integers between $1$ and $6 \cdot 10^6 = (60) \cdot 10^5$ are relatively prime to $60$.

Comment: Can you give me a hint as to how to count how many integers are relatively prime to 60?

Comment: @Newb  Anything not divisible by 2, 3 or 5  is relatively prune to 60.

Comment: That was actually apparent to me (as 2,3,5 are the prime factors of 60, and by transitivity of divisibility). I was actually wondering as to how to proceed from there.

Comment: You could compute the number that have a single factor in common, remove the doubles that get counted twice and possibly tweak the formula for those triple factors and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  what happens if $n$ is even? Are there other conditions on $n$ that can cause similar problems?